# scrollView in NavController will not reset after displaying keyboard (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have tried to follow other guides on here but to no avail. 
My app structure currently is a navigation controller that leads to viewcontrollers with scrollview embedded in them. The textfields, textview, buttons etc are on top of the scrollview. When the keyboard appears, and I dismiss it by tapping outside, the scrollview moves up with the keyboard, but does not come down. It seems like this problem is brought on by having the Navigation controller or the nav bar. How can I fix it?

EDIT: I just realized that every time I simulate that particular viewcontroller, everything in it is moved down the same distance before I tap on any textField/textView. Then when the keyboard is shown, it simply moves it up so it looks like how it's setup in storyboard. How do I get rid of the initial downward displacement?

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var activeTextView:UIView? = UIView()
@IBOutlet var main: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var initials: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var maleWord: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var maleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var femaleWord: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var femaleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var age: UITextField!


func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillBeShown:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)
}


func tapped() {
    initials.resignFirstResponder()
    main.resignFirstResponder()
    age.resignFirstResponder()
}
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
func keyboardWillBeShown(sender: NSNotification) {
    let info: NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    let value: NSValue = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.CGRectValue().size

    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    let activeTextViewRect: CGRect? = self.main.frame
    let activeTextViewOrigin: CGPoint? = activeTextViewRect?.origin
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeTextViewOrigin!)) {
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeTextViewRect!, animated:true)

    }

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
func keyboardWillBeHidden(sender: NSNotification) {

    self.scrollView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
    self .viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.activeTextView = nil
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

self.activeTextView = textView
scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {

self.activeTextView = nil
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    self.scrollView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: ("tapped"))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.main.delegate = self
    self.initials.delegate = self
    self.age.delegate = self
 self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update your function like following**

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden(sender: NSNotification) {

    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
    self .viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.activeTextView = nil
}
```

Comment: Still stuck..it only scrolls up with the keyboard and does not come down. thx tho

Comment: Check in storyboard if you have set Under Top Bars property for particular view controller. Try to unset it and check again. While unsetting it you may need to reset your frame for scrollview.